# Fractional-Recursive Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, fractions

Here from the fraction set we have a really hard question to be answered...suppose that a sequence is defined as $a_{n} = a_{n-1} - \dfrac 1{a_{n-1}}$, where $a_0$ is given.
...you already know what I'm asking you ... find the $n^{\text{th}}$ element of the sequence in terms of $n$ and $a_0$...fun! :)

P.S I've been trying for a lot of time ... but until now I haven't managed to find a solution; only some very weird graphs which can puzzle you...if you wish I can send you some of them!

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely that a closed-form solution can be found.  $a(n)$ is a rational function of $a(0)$ with numerator of degree $2^n$ and denominator of degree $2^n-1$.

Comment: Is it provably non-conjugate to something like $x^{2^n}$ or $\cos 2^nx$ ?

Comment: Well, there are some constraints on conjugacy.  The function $f(z) = z - 1/z$ on the Riemann sphere is two-to-one except for $f^{-1}(2i) = \{i\}$, $f^{-1}(-2i) = \{-i\}$.  The only fixed point is $\infty$, and there is just one $2$-cycle $\{\pm 1/\sqrt{2}\}$.

Comment: Counting small cycles would probably disprove conjugacy to any specific closed form by a finite computation, but ideally there would be a dynamical/ergodic invariant that distinguishes it from anything simple.